# Trouble with bookmarks in Emacs

Tags: function, emacs, bookmarks

I have some trouble with bookmarks, where I previously defined a function that worked just fine, though now it's not working anymore.

The error I am facing is when calling bookmark "last" it says "`Invalid bookmark last`", without quotes.

```
(defun go-bookmark-last () 
  (interactive)
  (bookmark-jump "last")
  (message "Went to most recent bookmark.")
)

(defun save-bookmark-as-last () 
  (interactive)
  (bookmark-set "last")
  (message "Save as most recent bookmark.")
)
```

These functions as macro's used to work no problem. Now the problem is that I can't visit my last bookmark until I "activate" bookmarks or something by using my "save-bookmark-as-last" function. Also, when I run the command `bookmark-bmenu-list`, then I can run the go-bookmark-last immediately. Somehow I need to "activate" the bookmarks before I can go to that last bookmark. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: "I can't visit my last bookmark until" is not very descriptive.  Tell us what happens (and not just "it doesn't work") when you try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you encounter this error when you restart Emacs. You are seeing this error because the bookmark file is not loaded. You can use `bookmark-maybe-load-default-file` function to load the default bookmark file. Modify your `go-bookmark-last` function like this:

```lisp
(require 'bookmark)

(defun go-bookmark-last ()
  (interactive)
  (bookmark-maybe-load-default-file)
  (bookmark-jump "last")
  (message "Went to most recent bookmark."))
```

Comment: I indeed tried to load-file and load "bookmarks" though it gave an error that way. Would you know how this error came to be, since it did not happen before? This fixed it by the way.